# Refresh Rate Button Php for Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, refresh, rate

Hello I have a refresh rate button in my page as we can see in the image below...

[image]

And what I want is to automatically refresh my page in the selected seconds.
My problem is that in Chrome when I select for example refresh rate equal to 1 it will refresh the page in the next second only once and I want to refresh it for example every 1 second if i previously select 1 second.

The second problem is with mozilla which when I load the page without select any refresh rate it refresh the page every second. How can I avoid that?

Here is my code...

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $link_address;?>">
<select id="refresh" name="refresh">
    <option value="-">Select Seconds</option>
    <option value="1">1 Second</option>
    <option value="2">2 Seconds</option>
    <option value="3">3 Seconds</option>
    <option value="4">4 Seconds</option>
    <option value="5">5 Seconds</option>
    <option value="10">10 Seconds</option>
    <option value="15">15 Seconds</option>
    <option value="30">30 Seconds</option>
    <option value="60">60 Seconds</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Refresh" name="refresh_rate"/>
</form>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="<?php echo $refresh;?>;URL=sensorData.php">
<br />
```

Comment: Unless it is really necessary, I wouldn't force a page refresh. It would probably be better for both aesthetics and implementation that you just use a timed AJAX call.

Comment: How are you getting and setting all of your variables?

Comment: @the_pete I have a POST in order to get the seconds `$refresh = ($_POST['refresh']);`

Answer (score 0):

as I know you need add the tag:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="<?php echo $refresh;?>;URL=sensorData.php">
```

between

```html
<head>
</head>
```

tags, before the body tag

Comment: it doesnt change something